# How to execute a python test using httpretty/sure

Tags: python, testing, httpretty

I'm new to python tests so don't hesitate to provide any obvious information.

Basically I want to do some RESTful tests using python, and found the httpretty and sure libraries which look really nice.

I have a python file containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sure import expect
import requests, httpretty

@httpretty.activate 
def RestTest():
    httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, "http://localhost:8090/test.json",
                           body='{"status": "ok"}',
                           content_type="application/json")

    response = requests.get("http://localhost:8090/test.json")
    expect(response.json()).to.equal({"status": "ok"}
```

Which is basically the same as the example code provided at https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty

My question is; how do I simply run this test to see it either passing or failing? I tried just executing it using `./pythonFile` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you looked into the `unittest` library?

Comment: well the question asks for HTTPretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your test is implemented as a Python function, then of course simply trying to execute the file isn't going to run the test: nothing in that file actually calls `RestTest`.

You need some sort of test framework that will call your tests and collate the results.

One such solution is [python-nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which will look for methods named `test_*` and run them.  So if you were to rename `RestTest` to `test_rest`, you could run:

```
$ nosetests myfile.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

OK
```

The `nosetests` command has a variety of options that control which tests are run, how errors are handled and reported, and more.

Python 3 includes similar functionality in the `unittest` module, which is also available as a backport for Python 2 called `unittest2`.  You could modify your code to take advantage of `unittest` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sure import expect
import requests, httpretty
import unittest

class RestTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @httpretty.activate 
    def test_rest(self):
        httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET, "http://localhost:8090/test.json",
                               body='{"status": "ok"}',
                               content_type="application/json")

        response = requests.get("http://localhost:8090/test.json")
        expect(response.json()).to.equal({"status": "ok"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running your file would now provide output similar to what we saw with
`nosetests`:

```
$ python myfile.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.012s

OK
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried calling your method?

Or does the annotation mean you don't have to explicitly call your method?

If I call your method, it seems like it works.  If I change the value on one side of the expect, it complains properly about the values not matching.